# How to change Accessory type -> Disclosure Indicator color in my cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I can't change the default `Accessory Type->Disclosure Indicator view`'s color in my UItableviewCell.

When I change tableviewcell tint color, it changes the following Accessory Type view color.

- Detail Disclosure
- Detail
- CheckMark

But I can't change the "Disclosure Indicator" color.

Do you have any other option to change 'Disclosure Indicator' color other than to set image in accessory view?

**Screenshots:**

Cell:
[image: cell]

Xcode menu:
[image: xcodemenu]

Comment: By changing tint color, you can change Disclosure Indicator color

Comment: @PPL  tint color affects other accessory type view's. It's will not change 'Disclosure Indicator' color. Please see the first screen shot.thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what each name means, but what I'd try is dragging from the view to view controller (create an outlet), and change the aspect with code. Either you nail the exact element, or if that is not possible, you can try using "dot notation" to see available sub elements and try styling those. I hope that makes sense, otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: @prabakaraniOS Please find my answer

Comment: Hey @prabakaraniOS Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your image in `accessoryView` and your problem solved.

Sample Code
Put this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 11, 22, 22)];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IconMore"];
cell.accessoryView = imgView;
```

[image]

Comment: there have any other methods to override the existing accessory views. Instead of setting the image in accessory view.

Comment: Not any other method to override the existing accessory views.

Comment: Thank you for accept this answer. If you want any other help please let me know.

Comment: thanks. currently, I have implemented which you mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide any option for this, you can do by creating custom *UIView*. Please find below custom View for the same,

```
import UIKit

class CustomDisclosureIndicator: UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    public var color: UIColor = UIColor.darkGray {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        let x = self.bounds.maxX - 3
        let y = self.bounds.midY
        let R = CGFloat(4.5)

        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: x-R, y: y-R))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x-R, y: y+R))
        context?.setLineCap(.square)
        context?.setLineJoin(.miter)
        context?.setLineWidth(2)
        color.setStroke()
        context?.strokePath()
    }
}
```

You can do following way,

[image]

Above code produces following output.

[image]

Try it once and let me know if any other queries are there.